# How to check if a DOM node is the `html` node

Tags: javascript, dom

EDIT: This is the dumbest question I've asked on SO. I'll keep it, to remind myself not to ask questions too quickly.

How can I check if the DOM node I have selected is the `html` node? I have noticed that it does not have the usual properties. For example:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html');

div instanceof HTMLElement; // true
html instanceof HTMLElement; // false

div.tagName; // "DIV"
html.tagName; // undefined
```

In particular, I would like a check that works for all DOM nodes (`div`, `span`, etc.). The issue is that my code crawls up the DOM and checks for a certain property; if the code does not find the property, it reaches the `html` node and throws an error because of this line:

```
if (node.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'OBJECT') { }
```

This throws a `TypeError` when `node` is the `html` node, because `node.TagName` is undefined.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `html` is not a single node, hence why it is different than `div`. Add the missing `[0]` like you do for your div reference!

Comment: Yeah, in the console you will get an undefined, because you're setting a var but not doing anything with it. Try `var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
console.log(html);` This will produce an expandable tree of the html node.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are looking at the *array* returned by `getElementsByTagName` instead of the first element returned. Try this:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]; // notice [0]

div instanceof HTMLElement; // true
html instanceof HTMLElement; // true

div.tagName; // "DIV"
html.tagName; // "HTML"
```

<sup>Note: tested in in Chrome Developer Tools Version 30.0.1599.101 m</sup>